# Remote Xdebug with PhpStorm

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

On my remote server I have xdebug installed and I am doing a port forward from my server to my local machine in order to debug. The issue is that the request is coming in and the mapping for files is prompted but when I choose the corresponding file PHPStorm show me the

> /var/www/html/index.php

like on the server. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I can complete my question with tech details if needed.

**Update 1**
https://imagebin.ca/v/3I2XzlNC7J8C

Comment: Can you show us your configuration under "Language & Frameworks > PHP > Servers"? Does your mapping show up correctly there?

Comment: Screenshots that would show what you have got there are more than welcome

Comment: guys, I've just uploaded a picture with Servers settings

Comment: Is your "Host" field on that screenshot is really empty or that's how you edit it? It should not be. Please show a screenshot of that popop/mapping files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-easier-debugging-of-remote-php-command-line-scripts/) a little old, but still valid blog post. In short, you need to define an environment variable `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` that will tell PhpStorm to use a specific mapping config.

For example, in Ubuntu you can do the following:

```
$ export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=yourServerName"
```

Instead of `yourServerName` you need to put the name of the server configuration that you defined in PhpStorm Servers Settings.